# Multiple checkbox set checked html

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, checkbox

I have an array in js that contains some name of checkbox i want to set checked.
The problem is i cannot do it properly and i dont know why i'm wrong
This is my code

```
var array = ['one','two word','three'];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length;i++)
$(':checkbox[value="'+array[i]+'"]').prop('checked', true);
```

With this HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="one[]" value="two word">
<input type="checkbox" name="one[]" value="four">
<input type="checkbox" name="one[]" value="one">
```

With this code my checkbox remain uncheked, can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 3):

True is not a valid property value for the `checked` attribute. The value can either be omitted or has to be `checked`

```js
var array = ['one','two word','three'];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {
    $(':checkbox[value="'+array[i]+'"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="one[]" value="two word">
<input type="checkbox" name="one[]" value="four">
<input type="checkbox" name="one[]" value="one">
```

Here's the specification from the W3C

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

Comment: The problem remains, this is a console log of the checkbox

[prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ":checkbox[value="Trieste"]"]context: documentlength: 0prevObject: n.fn.init[1]selector: ":checkbox[value="one"]"__proto__: n[0]

Comment: Is that the case? Can you run the code in the snippet?

Comment: yes but at this point i think there could be a problem somewhere else. I'll look now to find the problem :D Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me except for one item that had Three for a value instead of FOUR..

I modified your code and got all three to check You can set a value 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_value.asp

```
<input type="checkbox" name="one[]" value="two word">
<input type="checkbox" name="one[]" value="four">
<input type="checkbox" name="one[]" value="one">

var array = ['one','two word','four'];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {
$(':checkbox[value="'+array[i]+'"]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

here is a fiddle [Sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NinjaCodeMonkey007/rfxLyn2L/2/)